# Capturing MVC PHP view into a variable to pass as body mail in PHPMailer

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpmailer

I'm using a MVC framework and i want to pass a view into PHPMailer body but I can't capture the view into a variable.

Controller handling view looks like this:

```
// Load View
public function view($view, $data = []){
    // Check for view file
    if(file_exists('../app/views/'.$view.'.php')){
        require_once '../app/views/'.$view.'.php';
    }else{
        // View does not exist
        die('View does not exist');
    }
}
```

In controller i pass the view into the function sendMail but it first loads it than i get an error  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty:

```
$bodyMail = file_get_contents($this->view('booking/mailbody'));

sendEmail($bookingNumber, $id, $mailAddress, $bodyMail);
```

The helper function to handle PHPMailer function:

```
function sendEmail($bookingNumber, $id, $mailAddress, $bodyMail){

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set SMTP host name
$mail->Host = "*********";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Provide username and password
$mail->Username = "**********";
$mail->Password = "********";
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = "********";
$mail->FromName = "*******";

$mail->addAddress($mailAddress);
$mail->addAddress('*********');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Reservation confirmed: ".$bookingNumber.$id."";
$mail->Body = $bodyMail;
$mail->AltBody = "This is plain text of mail";

try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

My question is there's a way to capture the view into a variable?
Would you approach this in a different way? If so, can you guys give me the right direction to take?

Comment: Well you can either have your MVC have different rendering paths or try output buffering? what if you had a second function like `viewBuffered()` and captured and returned it with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: Is the `view` function something you have created? Can it be edited?

Comment: Note that when you use `require_once`, it will only return any contents the first time you call it, and in order to get anything out of it you either need to `return` it, or use output buffering to capture its output.

Comment: As @Scuzzy suggested i created a viewBuffered() function and it worked! I could have also add some parameters to implement the view() function as RJK said and make it work there instead, the first one looked easier though! Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I suggest using output buffering to capture the output of your view

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

And as @synchro suggest, review your usage of `require_once()`

```
// Load View, but capture it with output buffering
public function viewBuffered($view, $data = []){
    // Check for view file
    if(file_exists('../app/views/'.$view.'.php')){
        ob_start();
        require_once '../app/views/'.$view.'.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }else{
        // View does not exist
        die('View does not exist');
    }
}
```

-or-

```
// Load View, but capture it with output buffering
public function viewBuffered($view, $data = []){
    ob_start();
    $this->view($view,$data);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```